# is it possible to filter a table based on the results from another table in looker?

Tags: looker-studio, looker

I have two separate explores table 1 and 2.

Table 1: has name and state and I will filter by name, which will give me the person's name and their State.

example: |John|Florida|

Table 2: Has state and I need the results from table  to filter table 2

|florida| xxxx|xxx|xxxx

I can't combine them into a single table as this is for benchmarking and they need to be separated.

How can this be done?